Commuting/anticommuting properties of fermionic ghost fields in BRST Quantization
I was reading the paper "Batalin-Vilkovisky analysis of supersymmetric systems" (by Laurent Baulieu and others). I am struggling to understand how commutation/anticommutation relations of fields depend on their ghost number and Grassmann parity.
${\cal N}=2$, $D=4$ Fayet Sohnius multiplet is a specific example considered in the paper, and I have given the details below.
the ${\cal N}=2$, $D=4$ Fayet-Sohnius (FS) multiplet contains two complex scalar fields $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and two Majorana fermions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$
$$\begin{aligned}
& s_0 \varphi_1=-\sqrt{2} \chi_1 \psi_1-\sqrt{2} \bar{\chi}_2 \bar{\psi}_2+a^\mu \partial_\mu \varphi_1, \\
& s_0 \varphi_2=-\sqrt{2} \chi_2 \psi_1+\sqrt{2} \bar{\chi}_1 \bar{\psi}_2+a^\mu \partial_\mu \varphi_2, \\
& s_0 \psi_1=-\mathrm{i} \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_1 \partial_\mu \varphi_1-\mathrm{i} \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_2 \partial_\mu \varphi_2+a^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_1, \\
& s_0 \psi_2=+\mathrm{i} \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_1 \partial_\mu \bar{\varphi}_2-\mathrm{i} \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_2 \partial_\mu \bar{\varphi}_1+a^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_2,
\end{aligned}\tag{2.2}$$
where the $\chi_i$ (i= 1, 2) are the (commuting) constant
ghosts associated with the anticommuting Majorana spinor infinitesimal parameter of the ${\cal N}=2$ supersymmetry generators, $a_\mu$ is the (anticommuting) constant ghost associated with the four infinitesimal translation parameters. They have ghost number +1 and transform as;
$$\begin{aligned}
& s_0 a^\mu=+2 \mathrm{i}\left(\chi_1 \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_1+\chi_2 \sigma^\mu \bar{\chi}_2\right), \\
& s_0 \chi_1=0, \quad s_0 \chi_2=0 .
\end{aligned}\tag{2.3}$$
The authors say that the non-closure of the supersymmetry algebra shows up in $s_0^2 \neq 0$ and writes;
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_0^2 \varphi_i & =s_0^2 \chi_i=s_0^2 a^\mu=0, \\
s_0^2 \psi_1 & =2 \mathrm{i}\left(\chi_1 \bar{\chi}_1 \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_1+\chi_2 \chi_2 \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_1\right. \\
- & \left.\sigma^\mu \partial_\mu \bar{\psi}_2 \bar{\chi}_2 \bar{\chi}_1\right), \\
s_0^2 \psi_2 & =2 \mathrm{i}\left(\chi_1 \bar{\chi}_1 \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_2+\chi_2 \bar{\chi}_2 \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_2\right. \\
+ & \left.\sigma^\mu \partial_\mu \bar{\psi}_1 \bar{\chi}_2 \bar{\chi}_1\right) .
\end{aligned}
\tag{2.4}$$
They have also given the identity;
$$X Y=(-1)^{f_x f_y}(-1)^{g_x g_y} Y X\tag{below 2.3}$$
Where $f_x$ is the Grassmann parity of $X$ and $g_x$ is the ghost number of $X$.
But I cannot convince myself that this identity will give the results given above. For example if we try to explicitly calculate, $s_0^2 \varphi_1$ there will be a term $a^\mu a^\nu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \varphi_1$. For this to vanish, we need $a^\mu$ and $a^\nu$ to anti-commute. But since $a^\mu$ has grassmann parity 1 and ghost number 1, according to the above identity, they commute.
What am I missing here?

Yes, OP is right, the last eq. must be an error. Depending on conventions, 2 non-quantum form-valued fields $X$ and $Y$ supercommute in the sense that
$$ XY~=~(-1)^{|X||Y|+\deg(X) \deg(Y)}YX \qquad(\text{one convention})$$
or
$$XY~=~(-1)^{(|X|+\deg(X))(|Y|+\deg(Y))}YX \qquad(\text{another convention})$$
Here $|X|$ denotes the Grassmann-parity and $\deg(X)$ denotes the form degree of the form-valued field $X$.
In section 2 of Ref. 1 all fields are zero-forms, but higher form fields appear in section 3.
References:

L. Baulieu, M. Bellon, S. Ouvry & J.-C. Wallet, Batalin-Vilkovisky analysis of supersymmetric systems, Phys.Lett. B252 (1990) 387.



Does deg(X) contain the ghost number? 2. If there is a one-form field with ghost number 1, does it have a degree 2?


$\uparrow$ 1. No. 2. No.
